# Issue with multiple monitors (one is detected as built in, the other isn't detected)

Tags: ati, 14.04, multiple-monitors

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 (first time using it so I am pretty clueless) and I can't get my two monitors to be detected. When I go to the settings it detects one of them but it is recognised as a built in display and it doesn't let me toggle that off. Sorry if this is a stupid question but I can't find an answer. Thanks for any help in advance.

My graphics card is a Radeon 7870 HD Tahitin Edition.
My displays are mirrored and set to the same resolution.

Comment: I've used a utility called `arandr` to configure multiple monitors in the past with success. It's in the repos, so you can install it from the *Software Center*, or use this as an opportunity to use the command line. If you choose the second, `<ctrl><alt><T>` will open a terminal window, where you'd type `sudo apt-get install arandr`. Enter your password at the prompt.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for the answer (and Terminal tutorial) but it still only recognises one screen, it says default and I can't do anything with it?

Comment: @Marc I forgot to mention, both displays are on but they are mirrored and set to the same res.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the AMD Catalyst Control Centre using (http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install) and after the reboot both screens are detected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would try (and have used in the past):

- Install `arandr` from the Software Center or by typing `sudo apt-get
  install arandr` into a terminal window.
- Run arandr by typing it into
  the Unity dash. You should be able to see a graphic showing both
  monitors.
- You can drag them to any relative position as well as set
  the resolution of each. (I don't have a second monitor here, but you should be able to get an idea from this screenshot.0

[image]